# Edge won't load content

Tags: microsoft-edge

MS Edge is failing to load resources (css/images) from another domain via HTTP/2. I have added headers for CORS (works fine in Chrome).  I can load the resources directly by opening the URL in a new tab.

So I tried using Fiddler to see if I could find a request that was failing.  At that point it switched over to HTTPS and started working.

EDIT -  I thought this was due to HTTP/2, but I was able to disable HTTP/2 and problem is still happening.

Comment: CSS and images should not require CORS. What shows in network tab or console when it fails?

Comment: Content type is blank, received "(from cache)" (cleared cache)  Time 0s  result 200OK

Comment: Also was able to get HTTP/2 disabled, same result..

Comment: I don't know the issue but thought I will reply, HTTP2 only works with https, it doesn't  work with http so the page with http will load with http1.1 anyway.

Comment: [Microsoft Edge implements the HTTP/2 standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/dn905221(v=vs.85)), try to use clear the cache, then,  use F12 developer Network tool to check the request status.